# How do you change the textLabel when UITableViewCell is selected?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, didselectrowatindexpath

I want to change the textLabel and detailTextLabel of a cell when it has been selected.
I've tried the following, but no change occurs:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    MyAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MyPhoneAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"xxxxx";
    cell.textLabel.text =       @"zzzzz";
    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 10):

I agree, reloading the table view will actually dump and reload/display all the cells using `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and use the original data, not the updated @"xxxxx" and @"yyyyy" in your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

In a little test project I was able to change the labels upon selection with:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell * cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"it was tapped";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not be trying to reload the table while a cell is selected. Instead, try

> [cell setNeedsLayout]

after you make the above changes to the labels.

Also, is there a reason you're making a reference to the app delegate in the method?

Answer (score 2):

Try to reload the cell you selected (described by indexPath) :

```
[yourTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a New iPad Project (Split View) and Now go through the Classes->Files. The easiest way's been given there. The XCode's Generated Codes.

Sample Code Lines :-

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %d", indexPath.row];
```

You can use them in `cellForRowAtIndexPath ||&& didSelectRowAtIndexPath ..`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do with the delegate but you should try calling the tableView already instantiated; i.e. call

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
```

Maybe I'm not clear
What I'm saying is that you are instantiating a new empty table view

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [**tableView** cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]; //cell has nothing it is new.
```

consider replacing to call the old

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [**self.tableView** cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath]; //now you have one that has a textField already in it
```

Comment: Do you see what I'm saying? You're creating a new instance not the old one.

Comment: If you create a new one you must reload data to see it in the table view. If you use the old one the view will reflect the changes.

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to refresh only the selected cell instead of reloading the whole table ?

`[cell setNeedsDisplay];`

instead of

`[tableView reloadData];`

This will have better performance and I'm not but I suppose that selection is lost if you refresh the whole table (this may be the reason why you don't see any change in the end)....

Comment: What if you're using a custom cell view?

Comment: a custom cell view is a view set to the contentView of a UITableViewCell, so that's the same, the setNeedsDisplay will redraw the contentView.